# Many-To-One using Sequelize and NestJs

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, decorator

I'm trying to make a Many-To-One relation (each `Book` has one `Category`, but there are many `Book` with the same `Category`).

Nest always throws this error: `[ExceptionHandler] Foreign key for "Book" is missing on "Category".`

Why do I need a foreign key in my Category model ? Isn't it supposed to be the opposite, the Book that have a foreign key for the Category?

**book.model.ts**

```
@Table({tableName: 'BOOK'})
export class Book extends BaseModel<Book> {

    ... some fields
    
    @ForeignKey(() => Category)
    @Column({field: 'CATEGORY_ID'})
    categoryId: number // Category ID stored in my Database

    @HasOne(() => Category)
    category: Category    
}
```

**category.model.ts**

```
@Table({tableName: 'CATEGORY'})
export class Category extends BaseModel<Category> {
    @Column({field: 'NAME'})
    name: string

    @BelongsTo(() => Book)
    book: Book
}
```

**base.model.ts**

```
export class BaseModel<T> extends Model<T> {
    @Column({field: 'ID', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, type: DataType.BIGINT })
    id: number;

    ... some other stuff
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved,
I made it so the Category has a list of Book.

**book.model.ts**

```
@Table({tableName: 'BOOK'})
export class Book extends BaseModel<Book> {

    ... some fields
    
    @ForeignKey(() => Category)
    @Column({field: 'CATEGORY_ID'})
    categoryId: number // Category ID stored in my Database

    @BelongsTo(() => Category)
    category: Category    
}
```

**category.model.ts**

```
@Table({tableName: 'CATEGORY'})
export class Category extends BaseModel<Category> {
    @Column({field: 'NAME'})
    name: string

    @HasMany(() => Book)
    book: Book[]
}
```

Now working as expected